# c# .Net4 webRequest over SSL not working

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, https

Hi this works when posting to an http address but fails when posting to an HTTPS address with can't estabilish a trust relationship!

What do I need to do to this or is this a server error!?

```
private static string HttpPost (string uri, string parameters)
{
    //return "ok";
    // parameters: name1=value1&name2=value2    
    try
    {
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);

        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);
        Stream os = null;
        try
        { // send the Post
            webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;   //Count bytes to send
            os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);         //Send it
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "HttpPost: Request error",
               MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (os != null)
            {
                os.Close();
            }
        }

        try
        { // get the response
            WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
            if (webResponse == null)
            { return null; }
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "HttpPost: Response error",
               MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
   return null;
} // end HttpPost
```

Comment: You say it fails... what exception are you getting?  If you visit the https .site in a browser does it work properly?

Comment: BTW: Any reason you're using HttpWebRequest instead of [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) [.UploadValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx)?

Comment: System.Net.WebException was caught
  Message=The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
  Source=System

Comment: I'm using HttpWebRequest as I googled and could not find another way of doing an HTTP Post to a server...

Comment: @Adrian: WebClient is usually the best option to do HTTP requests, unless you need a specific feature that only HttpWebRequest provides. WebClient.UploadValues does an HTTP POST request.

Comment: thanks dtb I have webclient working for http but have same problem with https :(

Answer (score 1):

The SSL certificate is expired or invalid. Deploy a new, valid SSL certificate on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Or explicitly trust the cert if that is the right thing to do.

Comment: I found this code that works but not sure of the implications or if it will reside after exiting!?

Comment: ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate(object sender2,X509Certificate certificate,
X509Chain chain,SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
});